# Возможны ли конфликты со сторонним кодом при использовании Cookie и localStorage?

Tags: php, javascript

Насколько я понимаю на JS принято не засорять глобальный объект чтобы избежать конфликтов со сторонним кодом (различные библиотеки, дополнения, антивирусы и т.д.), поэтому часто применяется приём под названием модуль: `(function()){}(...)`.

Так вот аналогичный вопрос про использование Cookie и localStorage: имеет ли смысл делать какой то префикс к ключам чтобы избежать возможных конфликтов? Допустим не просто `key` а `mydomainru_key`.

Comment: значения в localStorage сохраняются для конкретного домена, зачем приписка?

Comment: Некоторые делают ключи с префиксами, например куки яндекс метрики  зовутся с _ym
У меня лично проблем пока ни разу не возникало, все-таки куки и стораджи в более-менее здоровом проекте захламляются не очень быстро, так что не скажу что это ужасно необходимая предосторожность. Но совсем необоснованной ее назвать тоже нельзя

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму Спасибо, Утка!